# AJAX request to retrieve XML output and on case redirect... but it doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having an issue with redirect once it retrieves the XML. Its a login that gets the values of ID username and ID password and checks to see if it exist. In this case, it shows the alert "worked" but doesn't redirect the page and I'm not sure why.

The query function on click goes as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        login();

    function login() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'dt_login.php',
          async: false,
          cache: false,
          data: {
            params: {
              op: 'authenticate',
              username: $("#username").val(),
              password: $("#password").val()
            }
          },
          dataType: 'xml',
          success: function(xml) {
            switch($(xml).find('message').text()) {
              case 'OK':
              alert( "worked" );
                window.location = 'http://www.newlocation.com';
              break;
              case 'DENIED':
                alert( "Incorrect username or password." );
              break;
              default:
                alert( "defualt" );
              break;
            }
          }
        });
    }
    });

});
```

dt_login.php:

```
<?php
function api($params) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://exampleurl.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print $output;

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($output);

    $_SESSION['user_id']= $xml->user_id;

}

if(is_array($_POST['params'])) { api($_POST['params']); }
?>
```

which outputs: 150OK1111swatkinsSAM WATKINS

Any ideas? Why does it show the alert but won't redirect?

Comment: Are you missing the `;` after the statements in your original code, too?

Comment: Actually had them before and removed them to see if it changed anything. Just updated the code. @AndrewBarber

Comment: Seems weird you are not cancelling the action unless what you are clicking is is not a button/link/form `$("#submit").click(function(evt){ evt.preventDeafult();`

Comment: Its indeed a form and the button is ID submit. Definitely weird right? Everything looks right @epascarello

Comment: So cancel the click like I showed you, does it magically work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not cancelling the form submission so you made a race condition. The form submits and you are trying to redirect. You need to cancel the form submission.

```
$("#submit").click(function (evt){ 
    evt.preventDeafult();
```

Ideally you would also hook up to the onsubmit handler on the form and not the click of the button. And using submit for a button name is a bad idea since it will have a name collision with `submit()`